# How to create indexed column names and in a loop in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, loops

I am trying to make column names for my dataframe(df) like

```
>> 'Frequency','molecule1','molecule2',.....'molecule18'
```

and make the 'Frequency' the index
However, my code does not work. the variable min,max, and columnNum is already set in the code
How should I fix it?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Frequency': np.arange(min,max+1)}, 
   columns=['Frequency','molecule{}'.format(x+1) for x in range(int(columnNum/2))]])
df.set_index('Frequency', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Also, please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: Do you want to create an _empty_ dataframe? (This is usually wrong.)

Comment: It is not good practice to use variable names which match imported objects within the same module. If you run pylint on your module, it will warn you about this. Therefore, the best thing to do is change your outer variable names from min, max to something more descriptive; like freq_mhz_min and freq_mhz_max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create an empty dataset for your molecules and you can create your index separately:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_min = 10
my_max = 15
ncols = 5

frequency = pd.Series(np.arange(my_min, my_max+1), name="frequency")
nrows = len(frequency)

data = np.full(shape=(nrows, ncols), fill_value=np.nan)
df = (pd.DataFrame(data, index=frequency)
      .rename(columns=lambda col: col+1)   # columns are currently 0, 1, 2... increase them all by 1 to become 1, 2, 3...
      .add_prefix("Molecule")              # add "Molecule" to the beginning of each column name

print(df)
           Molecule1  Molecule2  Molecule3  Molecule4  Molecule5
frequency                                                       
10               NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
11               NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
12               NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
13               NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
14               NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
15               NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```